# How to make compilation and obtain in pdf file the letters instead of formulas?

Tags: compiling, formulas

I use chat-gpt to polish English in my articles on physics. I use pdf created by latex, copy text to chat-gpt, and then change all formulas on letters like FFF or GGG. In this case, only, the chat-gpt works well. Is it possible to compile a latex file and change any formula for letters like GGG or FFF in pdf? I did not find a corresponding style and think it is possible to solve by using TeX code only in the preamble, but unfortunately, I'm not an expert in TeX code.

Comment: your questiion is very unclear. which letters do you want to change and what do you want to change them to?  Show a small document and say how you want to change it, but as far as I understand your question you should edit the source file in your text editor, not look for latex definitions.

Comment: @Mane32 Thanks, it looks very similar to what I want to do. I'd like to change ALL math environments like equation, align, eqnarry, and so on to the three letters, GGG for example. It is possible to modify the above suggestion to other math environments but I think it will be large implementation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd like to change ALL math environments like equation, align, eqnarry, and so on to the three letters, GGG for example. It is possible to modify the above suggestion to other math environments but I think it will be large implementation.

Comment: seems like it is a duplicate of the question @Mane32 referenced.